# Why is calling this list method returning an inaccessibility error?

Tags: c#, list, debugging, methods, compiler-errors

I've seem to run into an error that I've never run into before:

```
main.cs(9,48): error CS0122: `EratoPrimes.GeneratePrimes(int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
main.cs(15,15): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

exit status 1
```

Background: I am attempting to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes in C#. I believe I have the logic down of the algorithm fairly well, and have tested it with a `Console.WriteLine()` loop over the values (without returning the list of primes).

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EratoSieve{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        List<int> desired_primes = EratoPrimes.GeneratePrimes(100);
  }
}

public class EratoPrimes{
    List<int> GeneratePrimes(int limit){
        // set up indexed array of candidates:
        int[,] first_array = new int[limit,2];
        for(int i=0; i<limit; i++){
            first_array[i,0] = i;
            first_array[i,1] = 1;
        }
        first_array[0,1] = 0;
        first_array[1,1] = 0;

        // set up list for primes:
        List<int> primes = new List<int>(){2};

        // begin Sieve:
        for(int a=2; a < limit; a++){
            if(first_array[a,1]==1){
                primes.Add(first_array[a,0]);
                for(int b = a*a; b < limit; b+=a){
                    first_array[b,1]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        /* test to see indexed array:
        for(int k=0; k<limit; k++){
            Console.WriteLine(first_array[k,0]+" "+first_array[k,1]);
        }
        */
        return primes;
    }
}
```

Now, when I attempt to call the `GeneratePrimes` method in `Main`, I'm told that `EratoPrimes.GeneratePrimes(int) is inaccessible due to its protection level`. Why is this the case, and how can I rectify the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default methods without an explicit access modifier are private and thus only accessible within their specified class.

If you want to use it as you have defined, you could consider decorating it with the `public` access modifier and the `static` keyword :

```
public static List<int> GeneratePrimes(int limit){ ... }
```

This will do the following :

- `public` - The `public` access modifier will allow your method to be accessed outside of your current `EratosPrimes` class.
- `static` -  The `static` keyword will allow it to not require an instance of the same class and thus call it as you currently are using `EratosPrimes.GeneratePrimes()`. Without it, you would need to create an instance of your `EratosPrimes` class and then call the `GeneratePrimes()` method on that instance (i.e. `new EratosPrimes().GeneratePrimes(42);`)

Comment: Thank you. After looking up similar issues on SO (before asking this question), I knew the solution had to do something with making the method `public.` That just returned other compiling issues, and it wasn't until I read your (and Ehsan's) suggestion to add `static` that it worked. I will choose your answer since you explained why I should add `static`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you did'nt provided the access modifier in the method signatures, and by default the method is `private` in C#, you need to add `public` modifier if you want to access it from outside of this class, and the way you are calling it you will also need to make it `static` by adding the `static` keyword.

So your method signatures will become:

```
public static List<int> GeneratePrimes(int limit)
```